# Returning more than one value in filter using regex

Tags: mongodb, go, mux

I have a JSON file that follows a format like this for each record containing the names of various cities across the world.

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f856f2ee2d00c1818791982"
    },
    "name": "Sant Julia de Loria",
    "all_names": "Sant Julià de Lòria, Sant Julia de Loria, San Julia,San Julià,Sant Julia de Loria,Sant Julià de Lòria,Sant-Zhulija-de-Lorija,sheng hu li ya-de luo li ya,Сант-Жулия-де-Лория,サン・ジュリア・デ・ロリア教区,圣胡利娅-德洛里亚,圣胡利娅－德洛里亚",
    "alternate_names": "San Julia,San Julià,Sant Julia de Loria,Sant Julià de Lòria,Sant-Zhulija-de-Lorija,sheng hu li ya-de luo li ya,Сант-Жулия-де-Лория,サン・ジュリア・デ・ロリア教区,圣胡利娅-德洛里亚,圣胡利娅－德洛里亚",
    "country_code": "AD",
    "country_name": "Andorra"
}
```

My app basically returns the name of the city when querying it through a URL parameter. This is supposed to pass through a regex filter and then searches the JSON for the appropriate city name.

```golang
func searchCity(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // GET request that takes in a url param and returns a list of cities from the DB
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    values := r.URL.Query()
    city := values["city_name"]                                                               // Assigns url param from route `/suggest?city_name=` to 'city'
    cityCollection := client.Database(os.Getenv("CITY_DB")).Collection(os.Getenv("COL_CITY")) // Holds 'city' collection from DB

    if len(city) == 0 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"Error": "City name cannot be empty!"}`))
        return
    }

    filter := bson.D{ //Regex filter for querying the input through the DB
        primitive.E{
            Key: "all_names", Value: primitive.Regex{
                Pattern: city[0], Options: "i",
            },
        },
    }

    cursor, err := cityCollection.Find(r.Context(), filter) // Query to find city is declared with cursor
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"Error": "Could not execute cursor into query."}`))
        return
    }

    var cityList []City
    for cursor.Next(context.TODO()) { // Runs through each document entry in DB to see if regex matches
        var cities City
        err := cursor.Decode(&cities)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"Error": "Could not run cursor."}`))
            return
        }
        cityList = append(cityList, cities) // List of cities is appended to cityList
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    if len(cityList) == 0 {
        w.Write([]byte(`{"cities": []}`))
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(cityList)

}
```

The `City` type model that's used to create the `cityList` object holds the correct values.

```golang
type City struct {
    Name    string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Country string `bson:"country" json:"country"`
}
```

I've been trying to return the `country_name` along with the city name but I can't figure how to write it into the filter properly.

Comment: The database has `country_name` as the property name, so use that in the mapping: `Country string \`bson:"country_name" json:"country"\``. Also note that you should escape regexp if it comes from the user, you can't (shouldn't) use it as-is.

Comment: Well, `Name` uses `bson:"name"` for it and still calls the `all_names` property so I don't think that really changes anything. I did try it but it still returns just the city name.

Comment: If you need both the `name` and `all_names` properties, add a field for both in the `City` struct.

Comment: Nope, that's fine as is. Like I mentioned, I really just want to return the appropriate `country_name` for the city.

So if I wrote New York as the input, I expect there to be `name: New York` and also `country: United States` as part of the JSON response.

Comment: There is no `country` field in your MongoDB document, so if you use `bson:"country"`, it'll be empty. You must use `bson:"country_name"`. Please come up with a [mcve]. I think using regexp filtering and the web framework plays no role here. The question and problem is simply the mapping of documents into struct values.